# How to auto-replace words, such as acronyms, while typing?

Tags: substitute, insert-mode

When typing a report, we have a large list of acronyms defined in `Acronyms.tex`. In order to use it, we have to encapsulate an acronym such as `KDF` with the acronym command: `\ac{KDF}`. I often forget and find it rather cumbersome to type it every time.

I'm pretty sure I've seen auto-replacing in Vim, without using `:%s/x/y/` manually. It may have been a plugin or it may have been supported natively, I don't know.

Comment: I can't find it right now but I am fairly certain that we already have a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @statox Well, I'm happy to hear I'm not the only one who couldn't find it :)

Comment: Indeed :) I was just commenting to have a reminder to search it when I'll have more time, or to incite one of our long time user to link it if they find it more easily

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just noticed a disadvantage

That's because you're trying to remap *a command*. While "auto-replacements" in Vim are supposed to be done with *abbreviations* (see `:help abbreviations`).

You can create an abbreviation like that:

```
:inoreabbrev KDF \ac{KDF}
```

Unlike commands, the abbreviations are typed as usual. And the substitution takes place when Vim knows that `KDF` makes a whole word, not a part of it (e.g. `KDF<space> ---> \ac{KDF}<space>`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with hyphenations or slashes, such as in `CSMA/CD`, `SHA-1` or `Wi-Fi`. Do you have an idea how to solve that? Maybe I should use `inoremap` for those, though a lot of letters would then become 'dead' again.

Comment: @Luc see the help: some keys cannot be used

Comment: @Luc You can play with `iskeyword` option, like `set isk+=45,47` to allow your examples. But that could have some consequences, and, in general, cannot be recommended, unless you understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Luc Unless there are both acronyms with and without dashes and slashes you can define your abbreviations without them and put them into the expanded text, e.g., `:inoreabbrev CSMACD \ac{CSMA/CD}`or `:inoreabbrev SHA1 \ac{SHA-1}`.

Answer (score 4):

After some searching, it turns out that [single character replacements](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20443/14459) work just as well for words. The answer is:

```
:inoremap KDF \ac{KDF}
```

As the help text says: "Map the key sequence {lhs} to {rhs}".

When typing the specified word ("lhs") in insert mode, it will automatically be replaced (by the "rhs"). For example, when simply typing `When using a KDF for`, it will automatically be replaced and result in: `When using a \ac{KDF} for`.

Beware that this also works in replace mode, e.g. when your cursor is on the beginning of a line of text starting with `KEF testtest`, typing `RKDF` will not turn the line into `KDF testtest` or `\ac{KDF} testtest`, but into `\ac{KDF}test` instead (since you are in replace mode, it will overwrite the following characters).

And beware that fixing a single character will not trigger the replacement. It maps the key sequence, not the word. Replacing the "E" in "KEF" using `lrD` (turning it into "KDF") does not trigger the replacement.

**Edit:** I just noticed a disadvantage: any uppercase characters will now wait for the next character. If I defined inoremaps for `KDF` and `ABC`, then typing an `A` or a `K` in insert mode will wait for the next character (with a 1-second timeout) before moving the cursor ahead. If I type `KDF` too slowly (1 second between each character), it is not replaced. Neither behaviour is impossible to work with, but neither is desirable, either. If anyone has a better solution, please post it as an answer to the question so I can accept that as answer instead!

Comment: You need `inoreabbrev` as suggested by @Matt.  You may also be interested in [this article](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/08.html).